# How do I prevent a folder from reappearing in my home directory?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, directory, linux

I have a fairly standard Wordpress/WooCommerce site and I've found that once a day an empty folder called `shop` is created in the home directory. This causes issues with WooCommerce's redirect rules and prevents products being added to the cart (among other things).

Because the creation of the folder seems to be happening intermittently I'm finding it really hard to identify. Perhaps it's related to automatic updates, or some cron jobs running on a schedule, or it could even be user triggered in some way.

Does anyone know if there's a way to identify what script is creating the folder and/or how to block it from being created?

Comment: if your folder do not have a write permissions, then it must be some process running on your server. first make sure your seb server can not write to the root folder of the site, and if it still happens you will have to get someone to look at the processes that run on your server.

Comment: Thats interesting. Can you please share your website URL ?

Comment: The website is http://www.mylittlegeek.com. The WooCommerce AJAX calls don't work on any pages with /shop in the URL if there is a real /shop directory in the root. The shop directory is not currently present so no issue to see at that URL right now.